How to install window sashes into a shed wall?
How would old windows like these be installed?  Would you have to construct a face frame, and nail the face-frame to window frame, and then nail that face frame to your 2x4s and flash/tape over that?
It would be for a shed.


@DelphicOracle  I hadn't really decided when I asked the question. I was thinking of two stationary windows for light only, and then after reading the answer, a single up-down window that also provided ventilation; but after thinking it over, it seems that the optimal use might be to make two top-hinged awning windows.

Those are window sashes. They alone aren't to be installed as a complete window. Therefore, a jamb would be necessary, along with stops. "Face frames" aren't typically a window component.
That said, you can really screw these to your shed in any fashion you like as long as you don't nick the glass and crack them up. Short of a hurricane situation it's not critical how you do it.
I would build a frame of whatever depth you like out of one-by, five-quarter, or two-by lumber. Its interior dimensions should be slightly larger than the sash dimensions, by say ¼". Install those by fastening to the shed framing. Be sure they're square, level, and plumb.
Now add stops to one side, depending on ease of access. ¾" square works well, but they can be larger. 1x2 nominal could be ok, depending on frame depth. Add sealing tape or glazing putty to the inner faces.
Then set your sash in place and shim under it to center it up. Temporarily add a nail or screw at the top to hold it, and begin adding the opposing stops.
Optionally paint your parts before installation. Put on a final coat after all carpentry is done.
